# HAProxy uniform balancing between processes

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, multi-threading, multiprocessing

We using `nbproc 10` for multiprocess HAProxy. Server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz.

In config:

```
  nbproc 10
  cpu-map 1 0
  cpu-map 2 1
  cpu-map 3 2
  cpu-map 4 3
  cpu-map 5 4
  cpu-map 6 5
  cpu-map 7 6
  cpu-map 8 7
  cpu-map 9 8
  cpu-map 10 9
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket1  process 1
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket2  process 2
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket3  process 3
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket4  process 4
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket5  process 5
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket6  process 6
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket7  process 7
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket8  process 8
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket9  process 9
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket10 process 10
```

We observe a large **difference rps** between processes:
[image]

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the loadbalancing algorithm to leastconn instead of roundrobin.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but problem with balancing between process, not between backends.